# Minimum power of 2 that is greater or equal than a given value

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates

I want it to use with a class template, so it must collapse to a constant value.
I know, there are some answers already, but I can't make it compile. For, example, if I use this with my code, I am getting a lot of compiler errors (I am using VS 2013):

```
template<typename T,typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type,typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>::type>
T roundup(T value, unsigned maxb = sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT, unsigned curb = 1){
    return maxb <= curb ? value : roundup(((value - 1) | ((value - 1) >> curb)) + 1, maxb, curb << 1);
}


template <typename T>
union TEntry
{
    char    m[roundup(sizeof(T))];//data
    TDeadPtr<T> iNextDead;

    T* data(){ return (T*)&m; }
};
```

> > fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler. 3>  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\trees.h', line
> >     807) 3>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the
> >     program near the locations listed above. 3>  Please choose the
> >     Technical Support command on the Visual C++  3>   Help menu, or open
> >     the Technical Support help file for more information
> >     (....\dc\branch.cpp) 3>
> >     .h(443) : see reference to
> >     class template instantiation 'mem::TEntry' being compiled

Comment: What answers do you know, and why don't they fit? Please **edit your question** to improve it and motivate it.

Comment: "An internal error has occurred in the compiler." is always a compiler bug, and answers will need to be focused on that particular compiler to work around that particular bug. You now included enough information about that, but not enough code to reproduce the problem. For instance, you use `TDeadPtr` but never define it. Can you come up with a short source file to demonstrate the internal error?

Comment: the next minimal example produces the same kind of error.

Comment: #include <type_traits>

template<typename T,typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type,typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>::type>
const T roundup(T value, unsigned maxb = sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT, unsigned curb = 1){
 return maxb <= curb ? value : roundup(((value - 1) | ((value - 1) >> curb)) + 1, maxb, curb << 1);
}

template <typename T>
union TEntry
{
 char m[roundup(sizeof(T))];//data
 T* data(){ return (T*)&m; }
};

int main()
{
 TEntry<int> z;
}

Comment: @def That example fails equally with GCC, clang, MSVC. All complain that the expression is non-constant, which is expected when you use `const` instead of `constexpr`. After fixing that, with online versions of MSVC, it compiles successfully, so it still doesn't appear to demonstrate the problem you were asking about.

Comment: How to make it compile without constexpr (I am using msvc 2013 compiler)?